# Retrive some columns of relations in typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I need to retrieve just some columns of relations in typeorm query.
I have an entity `Environment` that has an relation with `Document`, I want select environment with just url of document, how to do this in typeorm findOne/findAndCount methods?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't add comment to post above. If you by not parsed data mean something like "environment.id" instead of "id"

try this:

```
return this.createQueryBuilder("environment")
      .getRepository(Environment)
      .select([
        "environment.id AS id",
        "environment.xx AS xx",
        "document.url AS url",
      ])
      .leftJoin("environment.document", "document")
      .where("environment.id = :id ", { id: id })
      .getRawOne();
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the object parsed, If I use getRaw the problem doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to use a querybuilder, here's an example:

```
   return  this.createQueryBuilder('environment') // use this if the query used inside of your entity's repository or getRepository(Environment)...
   .select(["environment.id","environment.xx","environment.xx","document.url"])
        .leftJoin("environment.document", "document")
       .where("environment.id = :id ", { id: id })
       .getOne();
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but when I use getOne  I receive an null, but getRawOne receive the record  but not parsed, any idea?

Comment: could you please share your code after you used createQueryBuilder?

Comment: for getOne it's for selecting the real entities from your database,in the other hand getRawOne it's for selecting some specific data, like sum,max .., so for that reason you get different form of data

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for me, and it doesn't require using the QueryBuilder. I'm using the EntityManager approach, so assuming you have one of those from an existing DataSource, try this:

```
const environment = await this.entityManager.findOne(Environment, {
    select: {
        document: {
            url: true,
        }
    },
    relations: {
        document: true
    },
    where: {
        id: environmentId
    },
});
```

Even though the Environment attributes are not specified in the select clause, my experience is that they are **all** returned in the results, along with `document.url`.

In one of the applications that I'm working on, I have the need to bring back attributes from **doubled-nested** relationships, and I've gotten that to work in a similar way, shown below.

Assuming an object model where an Episode has many CareTeamMembers, and each CareTeamMember has a User, something like the code below will fetch all episodes (all attributes) along with the first and last name of the associated Users:

```
const episodes = await this.entityManager.find(Episode, {
    select: {
        careTeamMembers: {
            id: true,          // Required for this to work
            user: {
                id: true,
                firstName: true,
                lastName: true,
            },
        }
    },
    relations: {
        careTeamMembers: {
            user: true,
        }
    },
    where: {
        deleted: false,
    },
});
```

For some reason, I have to include at least one attribute from the CareTeamMembers entity itself (I'm using the `id`) for this approach to work.